# Is energy rule violated here?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, wavelength

We know that for an EM radiation , energy is given by :

$$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$
[image].
Where $h$ is Planck's constant , $c = 300000000$m/s and $\lambda$ is wavelength of the radiation.
Clearly, energy is inversely proportional to wavelength . Hence , radiations with high energy should have less wavelength and vice-versa .
But why it is violated in this famous graph of Blackbody radiation v/s wavelength.

How the energy is increasing as wavelength increases (upto a maxima) ?
Image source: https://sites.google.com/a/coe.edu/courtney-s-chemistry/home/radical-black-body-radiation

Comment: What is plotted here is [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), not the dependence fo energy on the wave length.

Comment: This graph does not compare energy and wavelength. I don't see how you can directly infer anything from this graph about energy at particular wavelengths.

Comment: -Roger Vadim As far as I've learnt, EM waves and photons are not very far relatives .

Comment: @NuclearHoagie As we move towards the right  till the maxima ( i.e. on the right direction or say towards positive wavelength axis direction) , the corresponding intensity is increasing which violates that higher the energy of radiation , higher is the frequency and lower is the wavelength.

Comment: @Abbas Intensity is not energy. As you move toward the peaks to the right, you get more photons with less energy. A 3000K, an object radiates more at a wavelength of 1um than at 0.5um. That doesn't imply that 1um waves are more energetic than 0.5um waves, just that there are more of them.

Comment: Ok that explains that how curve looks like that. But , you shall explain that why there are more numbers and why do they decrease after reaching the peak ? Please describe reasons

Comment: I believe that it is site rules that if an image is used that was not created by the poster, then the post should give credit to the source of the image. This is usually done by providing the url for the source of the image. Please give credit for the image.

Answer (score 3):

> Is energy rule violated here?

No.

The energy *per photon* follows the equation:

$$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

The *total* energy at any wavelength emitted by a black body is the product of the energy per photon, times the number of photons emitted.

Your diagram shows the power density function of the radiation emitted by a black body by wavelength (for various temperatures). Power is the rate of energy transfer per unit time. For electromagnetic radiation, this depends upon both the *number* of photons passing through a surface in a given time, and their individual energy. The equation $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ gives only the individual energy of a photon of a given wavelength. But the diagram takes into account not only the individual energy a photon at a given wavelength, but also the number of photons (per unit time) at that wavelength.

[The diagram gives a power density function in two senses. First, amount of power emitted by a black body depends upon its surface area. (Or in the case of a *cavity* upon the area of the aperture to the cavity.) But the diagram also shows *density* functions in a sense similar to a probability density functions (if you are familiar with probability density functions). If you pick any two wavelengths, either near each other or far away, the power emitted by a black body per unit surface area for all the wavelengths between the two given ones is the area under the curve between the two given wavelengths.]

The power density function at first increases as the wavelength increases,  because the *product* of the photons individual energy times the number of photons emitted per unit time per unit area increases. This is true even though the energy of the individual photons is *decreasing* as the wavelength increases.

However, at each temperature, the curve reaches a maximum, and for wavelengths longer than the maximum point (for a given temperature), the *product* of the individual energy of a photon at a particular wavelength times the number of photons of that wavelength emitted per unit time per unit area *decreases*.

Comment: I think that graphs ( curves or slopes) shows the corresponding value of a variable which depends on another variable . Does the vertical axis represents total energy or average energy density for a corresponding wavelength ? I am thinking of the latter , unlike you , supposing total. If it's so , then please explain that why it decreases after that maxima ?

Comment: @Abbas what do you mean by "average"? Average over what?

Comment: Sorry , I meant "corresponding" by average .

Comment: That still does not make sense to me.

Comment: Corresponding means the value of energy ( or say intensity) corresponding to the corresponding wavelength.

Comment: The vertical axis corresponds to radiation energy per unit area per wavelength and hence not something like total energy

Comment: @Abbas I will edit my answer so perhaps you will understand.

Comment: I don't think that the answer is "edited" in any sense . Moreover , the area under the curve gives the total power between two selected wavelengths , don't look fine , as the area under the curve has the dimensions of (intensity*wavelength) don't give power dimensions. And in last , there is no elaboration and reasons that , for a black body , why it is increasing upto a maxima and then decreasing after it ( which one can easily say a characterstic of a black body to easily save himself

Comment: @Abbas 1) The answer is clearly edited, as can be seen by the edit history. 2) You are incorrect about the dimensions. 3) The phase "to easily save himself" borders on rudeness. Please communicate respectfully on this website.

Comment: I don't mean by "to easily save himself" to be rude . Indeed there is an edit , but of format only , and not of elaborations and reasons . Further , there is no emphasis of viewers on their answers . They tell me that number of photons is increasing. Just saying this doesn't answer question in any sense , as there is no reason provided by answerers that why is it increasing and upto that maxima why it decreases , etc ,. A good answer should not be just statements , but also giving logics proving their statements to be correct.

Comment: You always responded to image source citation , rudeness , etc etc but never gave the reasons which I asked several time in comments . This clearly shows that.......

Comment: @Abbas it shows what?

Comment: Again , you replied to my this comment so qhickly , but never responded to the reasons , elaborations that I wanted . It clearly shows that all the answeres including you either didn't understood my question very well and gave inappropriate answers .

Comment: Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

$E=hc/\lambda$ is the energy for a single photon. The curve that you see is the total radiant power for a black body. A black body does not emit the same number of photons at each wavelength. So the total radiant power has nothing to do with the energy per wavelength.

Think of it like inventory value. A store has widgets of types A, B, and C. One widget A is worth more than one widget B which is worth more than one widget C. The store has the same number of A and C, so there is more value in A, but the store has a lot more units of B, so even though each B widget is worth less than an A widget most of the store’s inventory value is B.

Comment: Radiant power , intuitively, shall be directly related to radiant energy ( I don't know much equations as I haven't even passed high school yet )

Comment: Yes, but the reason that the radiant power curve does not follow the energy per photon curve is that the number of photons is not constant across wavelengths

Comment: Read my comment in the answer given in below answer given by -Maths keep me busy

Comment: @Abbas I read your comments, I updated the answer. You are again missing the point that the energy formula is a per photon energy, and that the number of photons is not the same for all wavelengths

Comment: Ok , then please support your point that why numbers of photons is increasing? Also , why do they decrease after peak ? What happens and why that happens ?

Answer (score 0):

The wavelenght distribution of the light spectrum at higher temperature peaks at a lower wavelength, consistent with E=h/wavelength

Comment: No , just concentrate on any one curve ( i.e. any one curve for a fixed temperature)

Comment: Seems like you think the vertical axis is energy. It is not, it is the number of photons at each wavelength. Temperature is the Energy of the whole distribution curve or spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Each curve is obtained by measuring the energy from a blackbody, using a diffraction grating to select a narrow range of wavelength each time. The process is repeated for several temperatures, generating the curves.

So, it is an empirical result, not related to any assumption on the nature of the radiation. The notion of quanta of energy as a function of the wavelength was exactly the 'guess' used by Plank to explain the data. Because the energy requirements are greater for a potential candidate of smaller wavelengths compared to greater ones, the number of quanta decreases sharply at the left side of the graph, what explains the smaller measured energy in this range.